# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP in specific directory

Tags: nginx, centos, debian

I want to serve  `customers_api (directory)` in HTTP. Check below my current default.conf (I'm using Nginx and Centos 7). I've tried all examples that i found here, not work.

```
    server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    gzip off;       


    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;  

    server_name example.org;    

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }



    # certs sent to the client in SERVER HELLO are concatenated in ssl_certificate
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.org/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.org/example.org.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    # Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites, recommended 2048 bits
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;

    # intermediate configuration.
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:!aNULL;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (15768000 seconds = 6 months)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

    # OCSP Stapling ---
    # fetch OCSP records from URL in ssl_certificate and cache them
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    ## verify chain of trust of OCSP response using Root CA and Intermediate certs
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.com/ssl-bundle.crt;   

}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;  

    location / {
        # Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS with a 301 Moved Permanently response.
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location ^~ /customers_api/ {
        rewrite ^ http://example.org$request_uri? permanent;
    }   

}
```

Comment: You have Apache 2, but your configuration is from Nginx.

Comment: Yep. My bad, i have 3 dedicated servers, sometimes, i get lost. I'll fix.

Comment: Your configuration for http is somewhat confusing. Why are you using a permanent redirect? Your question needs to be made more clear, about what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your configuration.

You have HSTS (HTTP Strict Transport Security, [RFC 6797](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797)) enabled:

```
    # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (15768000 seconds = 6 months)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
```

This the main reason that causes any attempt to redirect HTTPS to HTTP fail. It's its very purpose.

(Otherwise, having HSTS is a really good choice.)

This is also the worst problem you have as all the browsers already seen this header won't allow HTTP for any connection to this domain for the 6 months specified in the `max-age`.

In case the application using your customer API doesn't have HSTS implemented, this may not be a problem for the application. Anyhow, it is harder to test whether the redirect is working or not, as your browser is now configured to do client side rewriting from HTTP to HTTPS.

When you have this solved, your current configuration still has other problems:

- You don't have a redirect from HTTPS to HTTP at all, e.g.

  ```
   server {
       listen 443 ssl http2;
       listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
       ...

       location /customers_api  {
           rewrite ^/customers_api(.*) http://$server_name/customers_api$1 permanent;
       }
   }
  ```
- You don't serve enything from HTTP server's `location /customers_api`, e.g.

  ```
   server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;  

       location / {
           return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
       }

       location /customers_api  {
           root /usr/share/nginx/html;
       }
   }
  ```
- Possibly you need the `location ~ \.php$` and some other configuration blocks on HTTP, too.

---

**Possible workaround.** Fortunately, you haven't set `includeSubDomains` in your HSTS. Therefore, only the `example.org` is forced to HTTPS. You could add a separate subdomain for these API calls, e.g. `http://api.example.org/customers_api`.